# IntelliSense won't work for MVC Razor cshtml page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor

I encountered

> There is no build provider registered for extension cshtml

error for one of my projects that use MVC 3. That makes auto-complete not work. The program still runs, but it's quite annoying.

I already have the Web.config in place and included all required references. As a matter of fact, my other projects that have the same configuration do not have the problem.

Am I missing anything other than checking the Web.config and references?

Comment: Is the cshtml file in the standard views or shared folder?

Comment: Are all the cshtml files in the project affected?

Comment: It is happened to me in VS 2010 after i installed VS 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem. When I Uninstall (Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools Update & Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3) patches from the computer. and Re-Install the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools Update Patch. It's working fine just like before.